# Line integral along the boundary of a square

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, contour-integration

> Calculate 
>   $$\int_\gamma(\cos x+\cos y+e^{x^2})dx+(\sin x\sin y+(y^4+1)^{\frac{1}{4}})dy$$ where $\gamma$ is the boundary of the square $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\times [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ with positive direction.

Any help? I don't know how to to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. By [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem), we are able to convert the line integral around the boundary of the square into double integral over the square: 
$$I:=\int_\gamma(\cos x+\cos y+e^{x^2})dx+(\sin x\sin y+(y^4+1)^{\frac{1}{4}})dy\\
=\iint_{[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\times [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]}\left(\frac{\partial (\sin x\sin y+(y^4+1)^{\frac{1}{4}})}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial (\cos x+\cos y+e^{x^2})}{\partial y}\right) dx dy$$
Note that after taking the partial derivatives, the integrand of the double integral is not so scaring:
$$I=\iint_{[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\times [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]}\left(
\cos x \sin y+\sin y
\right) dx dy$$
Can you take it from here?